# Page not found after migration to localhost. I already updated the sql links and the permalinks. Wp-admin page works perfectly

Tags: 404-error, migration, localhost

So basically whats in the title. I migrated the company website to my localhost to implement some changes. First I cloned the repository, then I created the database, and uploaded the sql file. Configured the wp-config.php file. Ran the sql querries to update the links in the databse, restarted everything, and when I go to the local host address it throws an "oops, page not found" error. What's weirder is that the wp-admin page works perfectly and I can see all the contents of the site in there, but whenever I try to open any page it throws the same "page not found" screen. The links seem to be working well too. And I even added this:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://localhost/example/' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://localhost/example/' );
```

To the wp-config.php file. I'm at loss here, because I did everything I usually do to migrate a site but couldn't get it to work. I searched here for an answer but most, if not all of them suggest the same fixes of:

"Update the urls in the sql" (done)
"Make the .htaccess writable and go to the permalinks page on wp-admin and save changes" (done)
"Update WordPress to the latest version" (I'm not allowed to make such decisions, especially because the site in live runs on an older WordPress, 5.4.1, and it works fine)

For the record, these are the sql querries I ran:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.example.org', 'http://localhost/example') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.example.org', 'http://localhost/example');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'http://www.example.org', 'http://localhost/mysite/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'http://www.example.org', 'http://localhost/example/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'src="http://www.example.org', 'src="http://localhost/example/');

UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `guid` =  REPLACE( `guid` , 'http://www.example.org' , 'http://localhost/example/' ) WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment';

UPDATE wp_posts SET  guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://www.example.org', 'http://localhost/example/') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

Where "example" is the site im working on, but I cant share due to company policies. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Remove trailing slashes in those two defines.

Comment: I already tried that and its the same result...

Comment: Did you try deactivating all plugins, and reverting to starter theme, just to check?
Also, I have had problems like this before, where I had to delete .htaccess, and THEN save permalinks - it's worth a shot.

Comment: Using SQL to update URLs is really tricky, especially when some data may be stored in serialized formats. You might want to try starting from scratch and using WP CLI's [`wp search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) function which takes into account more complex replacements, particularly with the `--precise` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer by myself. It was rather simple. The localhost server I was running uses PHP 8.0, while the website I was trying to migrate runs on WordPress 5.4.1 using PHP 7.3. All I had to do was to configure xampp to run PHP 7.3 on that particular project and done. The site showed up without any issue.

So I'm debating between deleting the question or leaving it up, because it was a dumb problem, but also it's a pretty good educative tool of why you should always check that your localhost server uses the same versions of the live server.

Comment: But this is not supposed to happen. I have all major PHP versions installed on my development machine ( 5.6, 7.0, 7.3, 7.4, 8.0 ) and I switch versions regularly without a problem. There must have been an issue with the configuration. You can trying using `phpinfo();` and then compare the output using a tool such as WinMerge.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as my research took me, WordPress 5.6 is the first version of WordPress to support PHP 8,  while this current project runs on WordPress 5.4.1. All the issues I was having with the broken links got fixed when I downgraded the php version for that specific project.